# Why my father gaining weight even after eating less food per day for years

Tags: weight, body-weight, overweight

I am posting this question as I am concerned about my father's health. He is 60 years old, 5feet 5 inches height and has 86kgs weight.

he worked(now he is taking rest at home) in a rice mill and traveled around 4 -5  kms per day on bicycle for 25 to 30 years.

He used to eat just 400 grams of rice during his service per day, but he still gained 86 kgs of weight. I know that energy cant be created and cant be destroyed then may I know how he gained that much of weight. My grand father and grand mother are thin. He always eats home food only. Moreover he is a vegetarian only

Please answer to help me understand about his health.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you saying he went from working and riding a bike daily to doing neither of those things and he has since gained weight?

Comment: He rode bicycle not bike daily to work area, I mean he worked hard but still why did he gain more weight even eating less food

Comment: @user2225190 Perhaps he is retaining water? If you have noticed any swelling, it would be high time to visit a doctor because that would be an early warning of heart failure.

Comment: Are you saying he eats 750g of rice PER DAY?

Comment: @JJosaur: Sorry he eats 400 grams of food per day

Comment: @L.B: Could you please help me how to know(do you suggest any diagnostics) if all that is water or food. Also let me know which specialized doctor can help us understand this.

Comment: @user2225190 You can tell if it is edema by putting gentle pressure on a foot or leg, if the indent from your finger bounces back immediately it is not swelling. However, if the indent from your finger lasts for a few seconds, it may be swollen. If you think it is swelling and it is often swollen then you should visit a cardiologist.

Comment: 400g cooked rice is still a lot of rice. That is still a lot of calories!

Comment: Cooked how? 400g steamed rice would be around 1600 [kcal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie), in oil or similar, can easily be 3000 kcal.